# In MVC, what layer should be responsible for building lists of Things for certain contexts or views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, architecture

An example: When using [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari), or any other "paging" mechamism using scopes, you call that scope on the model.

```
SongsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @songs = Song.most_popular_with_covers.page(params[:page]).per(10)
  end
end
```

I'm trying to find out if this is the right place. In pure MVC, I would expect such calls (like limits, orders, and so on) to be handled by the model-layer. To illustrate with an IMHO bad example:

```
SongsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @songs = Song.order_by(:listen_count, :desc).includes(:albums => :covers).page(params[:page]).per(10)
  end
end
```

I am now putting knowledge about how "popularity" is calculated into my controller, my controller needs to know how to fetch the cover image, it needs to know how songs, covers and images are connected and so on. So, to go all the way to the opposite side (skinny controller):

```
@songs = Song.paged_most_popular_with_covers(params[:page])
```

Yet that quickly turns into a spagetti of methods on the models (fat models). Lets say some context needs them paged, but only get the top-5, e.g. for a side-bar-widget:

```
Song.paged_most_popular_with_covers(page: 1, per: 5) #or
Song.paged_top_five_with_covers #or
Song.paged_top_with_covers(amount: 5)
```

You could extend this behaviour to other concepts as well: fetch a list of resources for a select-field (ordered differently, not paged, `pluck` only name and id etc.), fetch a list of resources for a sidebar-widget (only need title and id, ordered and limited differently) and so on.

In that case the question becomes broader: "Should the models care about sending back lists, ready to be used in context C for view V, or should models send back dumb lists and have the controller manipulate these?".

Comment: Emm .. "pagination" as whole is part of UI logic. Why would model layer (or in case of Rails: collection of SRP violations, known as ActiveRecord) would have any concept of "page size"?

Comment: It's the job of the model to provide data on demand.  Eg, to have methods which take page size and other parameters into account when returning a collection of data.  It's the job of the controller to *decide* what to ask the model layer for.  I don't understand why you think this `@songs = Song.order_by(:listen_count, :desc).includes(:albums => :covers).page(params[:page]).per(10)` is a bad example - what's bad about it?

Comment: @tereško That is what I was thinking. Yet it is a common pattern in many Rails applications to call scopes like `page(1).per(10)` in the controller. Are you saying that should even go to the view layer? If so, would a Presenter-pattern/Decorator be the place to munge a collection into a paged collection?

Comment: @MaxWilliams because you are pulling knowledge of how e.g. albums and covers are related to a Song into the controller. IMHO a controller should not know about that: it's the responsibility of the Models to return the proper "cover image", it knows best where and how to fetch these. Order-by is "bad" because now my controller has knowledge about how a Song's popularity is calculated. EDIT: clarified this in the Q as well.

Comment: This is why people say that "you cannot do classical MVC on web", because neither model layer nor view instances can keep the state between requests. The cleanest options would be to have a service which is shared between controller and view and manages the songs. Then in the controller you set the user-provided page value for that service and from the view request the "current page" by also indicating how large that page should be. Basically: **it's tricky** and only worth the effort in large projects.

Comment: @tereško do you happen to have an url of someone saying that? I'm very much interested in reading more about this. Also: yes, this is a large project.

Comment: I think the super-strict MVC that you're describing is unattainable.  There's always going to have to be some bleed-over between the layers, pragmatically speaking.